# splitting words into syllables python

Tags: python

I have a function called syllable_split(word_input) that receives a word and counts the number of Syllables and returns only a list containing the syllables of the given word.
e.g.
pandemonium ----> ['pan', 'de', 'mo', 'ni', 'um']

self-righteously ---> ['self', 'right','eous', 'ly']

hello ---> ['hel','lo]

diet ----> ['di','et]

seven ---> ['sev','en']

my function counts the syllables correctly but I'm having trouble splitting the word to its corresponding syllables. I only managed to split the word to its first correspondent syllable but it tends not to work for some words.For example I enter in 'seven' and I only get 'se' instead of 'sev'. I was thinking of following the syllable division pattern(vc/cv,c/cv,vc/v,v/v) but I'm having trouble implementing that into my function.

```
def syllable_split(word_input):
count = 0
word = word_input.lower()
vowels = set("aeiou")
syll = list()
temp = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1
if count == 1:
    return word
for index in range(count, len(word)):
    if word[index] in vowels and word[index - 1] not in vowels:
        w = word[temp: index - 1]
        if len(w) != 0:
            syll.append(w)
            temp = index - 1
return syll

user_input = input()
print(syllable_split(user_input))
```

Comment: Is this a programming question or an English language question?

Comment: There is no simple algorithmic approach to doing this. It's related to hyphenation so you could investigate that. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification), the algorithm used in TeX is widely used; here's a [Python implementation of it](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/hyphenate.html). There's also [Pyphen](https://pyphen.org/), which uses a dictionary. The difficulty is that hyphenation algorithms often want to keep the last segment of a word together even though it's more than one syllable (e.g. hyphenation -> hy-phen-ation).

Comment: You could also try https://dictionaryapi.com/ -- it's from Merriam-Webster and is free for non-commercial use up to 1000 requests a day.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with the comments that your approach will have many failings, but if that's okay, based on your implementation you could write a function that splits the words exactly how you describe:

```
vowels = 'AEIOU'
consts = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
consts = consts + consts.lower()
vowels = vowels + vowels.lower()

def is_vowel(letter):
    return letter in vowels 
def is_const(letter):
    return letter in consts

# get the syllables for vc/cv
def vc_cv(word):
    segment_length = 4 # because this pattern needs four letters to check
    pattern = [is_vowel, is_const, is_const, is_vowel] # functions above
    split_points = []

    # find where the pattern occurs
    for i in range(len(word) - segment_length):
        segment = word[i:i+segment_length]

        # this will check the four letter each match the vc/cv pattern based on their position
        # if this is new to you I made a small note about it below
        if all([fi(letter) for letter, fi in zip(segment, pattern)]):
            split_points.append(i+segment_length/2)

    # use the index to find the syllables - add 0 and len(word) to make it work
    split_points.insert(0, 0)
    split_points.append(len(word))
    syllables = []
    for i in range(len(split_points) - 1):
        start = split_points[i]
        end = split_points[i+1]
        syllables.append(word[start:end])
    return syllables

word = 'vortex'
print(vc_cv(word))
# ['vor', 'text']
```

You can do something similar for the other patterns, for example, c/cv will be `patterns=[is_const, is_const, is_vowel]` with a segment length of 3

- Note
  You can put functions in list:

```
def linear(x):
    return x
def squared(x):
    return x * x 
def cubed(x):
    return x * x * x 

funcs =  [linear, squared, cubed]
numbers = [2, 2, 2]
transforms = [fi(ni) for ni, fi in zip(numbers, funcs)]
# results -> [2, 4, 8]
```